support for a parameter with an index in the query String when bound to @RequestParam
Spring version:2.5.2
Many http clients pass an array to queryString in this form:
?attributes[]=field1&attributes[]=field2

I'm trying to get Controller to work with this format through RequestParam:
@RestController
public class FooController {
   
   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET,
    value = "/foo",
    produces = "application/json")
   ResponseEntity<FooDto> getFoo(@RequestParam(value = "attributes", required = false) List<String> attributes) {
   }
}

However, when executing a request, null is passed to the controller method as the attributes value.
I found that the "RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.resolveName" method receives "attributes" as the value of the parameter name, while this parameter is stored in the request object using the key "attributes[]". Therefore, the argument of the controller method is null, because resolver cannot find a match.
My questions:

maybe spring mvc has support for this format "attributes[]=field1&attributes[]=field2" when using @RequestParam? WebDataBinder#adaptEmptyArrayIndices support it
I tried to write an extension for RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver. Is it correct to place such logic in the resolver itself?

@Component
public class SpringMvcConfig implements WebMvcRegistrations {

  @Override
  public RequestMappingHandlerAdapter getRequestMappingHandlerAdapter() {
    return new CustomRequestMappingHandlerAdapter();
  }

  public static class CustomRequestMappingHandlerAdapter extends RequestMappingHandlerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void setArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
      if (argumentResolvers == null) {
        return;
      }

      int buildInRequestParamResolverIndex = IntStream.range(0, argumentResolvers.size())
          .filter(i -> {
            var resolver = argumentResolvers.get(i);
            return !(resolver instanceof RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver);
          })
          .findFirst()
          .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException(
              "The RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver could not be found! It may be necessary to change the solutions "
              + "for registering a custom resolver."));

      var customResolver = new CustomRequestParamMethodArgumentResolver(getBeanFactory());
      var updatedResolvers = new ArrayList<>(argumentResolvers);
      updatedResolvers.set(buildInRequestParamResolverIndex, customResolver);
      super.setArgumentResolvers(updatedResolvers);
    }
  }

  @Slf4j
  public static class CustomRequestParamMethodArgumentResolver extends RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver {

    public CustomRequestParamMethodArgumentResolver(boolean useDefaultResolution) {
      super(useDefaultResolution);
    }

    public CustomRequestParamMethodArgumentResolver(
        ConfigurableBeanFactory beanFactory, boolean useDefaultResolution) {
      super(beanFactory, useDefaultResolution);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter parameter) {
      return super.supportsParameter(parameter);
    }

    @Override
    protected Object resolveName(String name, MethodParameter parameter, NativeWebRequest request) throws Exception {
      if (
          (
              parameterTypeIs(List.class, parameter) || parameterTypeIs(Set.class, parameter)
          )
          && nameIsIndexParameter(name, request)) {
        return super.resolveName(name + "[]", parameter, request);

      }
      return super.resolveName(name, parameter, request);
    }

    private boolean parameterTypeIs(Class<?> parameterType, MethodParameter parameter) {
      return parameterType.isAssignableFrom(parameter.getParameterType());
    }

    private boolean nameIsIndexParameter(String name, NativeWebRequest request) {
      return request.getParameterMap().containsKey(name + "[]");
    }
}


This was cross-posted in https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/32577
